# Trying to understand the inverse transform method for generating a Poisson random variable

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics, simulation, distribution

The algorithm [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) gives for generating Poisson-distributed random variables using the inverse transform method is:

```
init:
     Let x ← 0, p ← e^−λ, s ← p.
     Generate uniform random number u in [0,1].
while u > s do:
     x ← x + 1.
     p ← p * λ / x.
     s ← s + p.
return x.
```

I implemented it in R:

```
f<-function(lambda)
{
x<-0
p<-exp(-lambda)
s<-p    
u<-runif(1)    
while (u>s )
{
   x<-x+1    
   p<-p*lambda/x    
   s<-s+p
}    
return(x)
}
```

but I don't understand how this generates values of this random variable, and I also think the code is incomplete because the output is always `1`.

Could someone please explain?

Comment: Are you familiar and comfortable with the inverse transform approach for continuous random variates?  How about for discrete random variates other than the Poisson?

Comment: @pjs I am not yet familiar with the inverse transform approach for continuous random variates. And somehow familiar with the discrete random variates :) .Why?

Comment: I was trying to figure out what was a reasonable starting point to address your question.  You might check out Section 4.3.1 and Appendix A of [this paper](https://www.informs-sim.org/wsc07papers/007.pdf).  If that makes sense to you, I'll take a stab at how discrete inversion works for the Poisson.

Comment: @pjs I've checked the mentioned paper, yes it makes sense somehow.

Answer (score 1):

For Inverse transform sampling of poisson distribution,  I suggest (e.g.) reading  Chapter 4 in `Simulation (2006, 4ed., Elsevier)` by Sheldon M. Ross.  Then according to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) steps mentioned, you can try following R coding

```
pois_wiki = function(n, lambda){
  ### Inverse transform sampling for poisson distribution
  ### ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution
  ### note: work efficiently for small λ
  X = rep(0, n) # generate positions for n samples
  for(j in 1:n){ # for each j-sample we do following wiki steps:
    x = 0; p = exp(-lambda); s = p
    u = runif(1) # Generate uniform random number u in [0,1]
    while(u > s){
      x = x + 1
      p = p*lambda/x
      s = s + p
    }
    X[j] = x # put generated sample for X in j-th element position
  }
  X # return n samples
}

### test in R
### note: for X~possion(λ), E(X)=Var(X)=λ
### set.seed(0) for reproducibility
n = 10000; lambda = 3
set.seed(0); mean(pois_wiki(n,lambda)); var(pois_wiki(n,lambda))
# [1] 3.005
# [1] 2.983695
```