# Loop with random increment

Tags: r, matlab, while-loop

Consider the following code (Matlab)

```matlab
function counter = ross_fpt_uniform
%ROSS_FPT_UNIFORM generates the first passage time of the sum of uniform
% random variables exceeding level 1.
    s = 0;
    counter = 0;
    while (s <= 1)
        s = s + rand(1,1);
        counter = counter + 1;
    end
end %ross_fpt_uniform
```

I am having problems translating `function counter = ross_fpt_uniform` into R

It confuses me how I should treat the `counter` because here `counter = counter + 1;` seems like it's a variable. Is it a function or a variable and how do I write it in R?

My current r code is as follows:

```r
counter<-function() {
  s<-0 
  counter<-0 
  while(s<=1){
    s <- s + runif(1) 
    counter <- counter+1
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_functions.htm

Comment: @HectorHaffenden `counter<-function() {s<-0 counter<-0 while(s<=1){s<-s+runif(1) counter<-counter+1}}` though this a part of a bigger program and it's somehow nested, the thing is it does not work

Comment: you probably need `counter <<- counter + 1` (e.g. read about scoping on http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html)

Comment: @Isa - Read the link I provided.  `counter` isn't the name of the matlab function.

Comment: `counter` is a variable which starts at `0` and just increases by `1` each loop. You're outputting it from the MATLAB function.

Comment: @Wolfie Should I have something like this `ross_fpt_uniform<-function() {s<-0 counter<-0 while(s<=1){s<-s+runif(1) counter<-counter+1} show(counter)}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're missing is a `return(counter)` statement.

```
counter<-function() {
  s <- 0 
  counter <- 0 
  while(s<=1){
    s <- s + runif(1) 
    counter <- counter+1
  }
  return(counter)
}
```

Try it out:

```
set.seed(101); cc <- replicate(1000,counter())
plot(table(cc))
```

[image]

Comment: Why does it shows an error message, Error in counter(): could not find function "counter" and other that could not find 'cc' object ?

Comment: Would you mind to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55427848/code-to-evaluate-an-integral-from-matlab-to-r-not-doing-was-expected ?